# Observation on Rubik's Cube's tiles

Tags: rubiks-cube

Might be a naive question.

While playing with a Rubik's cube, my cousin noticed that at least 2 tiles of same colour (any one of the six colours) always remain adjacent to each other.

Is this always true ? If yes, can it be proven mathematically ?

Comment: No it is not true.  See the [super flip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superflip) for a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked on the internet quite a [few](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/429/is-it-possible-to-scramble-a-rubiks-cube-such-that-no-two-squares-of-the-same-c) [times](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52975/is-it-possible-to-scramble-a-rubiks-cube-so-that-each-face-has-no-more-than-2-s/53002) [before](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/4xv94k/is_it_possible_to_permute_a_rubiks_cube_such_that/).